# Dispatch a similar URL to different apps depending on user status

Tags: django

I have 2 apps, Registration and Albums. If the user visits the '/' or '/home' then they should  see either the registration/login form or their album management page depending on whether the  user is logged in or not.

Is there an established best practice for how to dispatch a similar URL between 2 different apps? Is there a way to build this so that either App does not need to know about the other?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your needs are restricted to showing a login form if the user is not logged in vs showing the "home page" when the user is not logged in, I'd recommend that you use the "login required" decorator.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def show_home(request):
    """
    Show home page...
    """
    ...
```

This decorator can be applied at the view level ( as shown above ) or in urls.py ( as shown below ):

```
url(r'^reports/', login_required(ListView.as_view(
    template_name="...",
    queryset = ...,
    context_object_name = ...
))),
```

The second pattern is commonly used with generic views and class based views.

Both solutions presuppose that you are hooking into Django's built in login / registration apparatus ( with customized templates and customized views where needed ). If you are using a custom registration / auth framework, it will still be a good idea to use a decorator pattern.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `LOGIN_URL` to `/registration/login`, and decorate your `/` view with `@login_required`, then they will automatically be redirected.

Answer (score 0):

when user signs-in add a variable to session and check it on the / or /home request.